# Why is ActiveRecord empty when I call from a Controller test, while it is not empty when I do a get request outside of the test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, activerecord, minitest

I have a test code like so

```
  test "reward/balance with existing id returns 200" do
    get "/reward/balance?id=4"
    assert_response(200)
  end
```

but when I run that, I get a response that's different from when I do the same GET request outside of the test.

For example, if I run http://localhost:3000/reward/balance?id=4 from my browser I get the response I want. I found that for some reason when I call from the test, the ActiveRecord is empty.

The function that's called when doing a GET at the URL is as below

```
def show
    if params[:id]
        if user = User.where(id: params[:id]).take
            render json: user["reward_balance"], status: :ok
            return
        else
            render json: {message: "#{User.all.inspect}"}, status: :bad_request
            return
        end
    else #If no id in params
        render json: {message: "Incorrect parameters"}, status: :bad_request
        return
    end     
end
```

I put `render json: {message: "#{User.all.inspect}"}, status: :bad_request` so I can see what it prints when called from the test.

When called from the test I get `"{\"message\":\"#\\u003cActiveRecord::Relation []\\u003e\"}"` so we can see that the ActiveRecord User is empty.

However when I call User.all from the rails console, the ActiveRecord User is populated.

Why is it showing different results when called from the test?

Comment: Rails use different databases for development and test environment. You need to create users before the test case using the `setup` block. Also, if you want to check content in console use `RAILS_ENV=test rails console` to go in test mode

Comment: Thanks for that answer. Is the database for the test environment reset for each test run? If I want it to have it reset and load_seed for each test run, do I need some type of reset command in the setup block?

Comment: It gets automatically cleared out between test runs, this doc had some decent information on setting up fixtures to use in your tests: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3/testing.html